# update view whenever data inside service changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
angular.module("taskAssign")
    .service('shareData', function(){
    this.assignees = "dummy";
});
.directive("textArea", textAreaDir)

function textAreaDir(shareData){
    return{
        restrict:'EA',
        template:'<textarea></textarea>',
        replace: true,
        scope : {

        },
        link:function(scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller,ngModel){
             scope.$watch(shareData.assignees,function (old,newv) {
                 console.log(old);
                 console.log(newv);
             });

        },
        controller:function($scope){
        $scope.$watch('shareData.assignees', function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
            if(newVal) { 
              console.log(newVal);
            }
          });
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to update the view in textArea directive with ltest values of sharedata service,it is only showing the initial value of shareData service later if shareData updates view is not updating

Comment: Please provide your html

Comment: Anik Islam Abhi thanks for your reply , I am regret to say that I am not able to share html now at this point as I mentioned I just wanted to update my textarea content through service, when ever or where ever service updates it should update my text area

Answer (score 1):

You need to put watch as a function on service variable `shareData.assignees`, basically that function will evaluate on each digest cycle.

And inside your controller you need to inject `shareData` service dependency to use it.

**Code**

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return shareData.assignees; //this will evaluate on each digest, and run callback when value gets changed.
}, function(old, newv) {
    console.log(old);
    console.log(newv);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

create shareData variable in your scope, then watch will trigger

```js
controller:function($scope){
        $scope.shareData = shareData
        $scope.$watch('shareData.assignees', function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
            if(newVal) { 
              console.log(newVal);
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: $scope.shareData = shareData
this line will usefull